# Mask credit card and pin from String in java

Tags: java, regex, string

Need to mask only 14 digit Credit card number and pin using regular expressions

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Mask{ 
    static String text="+919913623683,,,,1,2,,,4328798712363938,,,,5673,,7,8";
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(replaceCreditCardNumber(text));
    }
    public static String  replaceCreditCardNumber(String text){
    String result = text.replaceAll("(\\d{16}(\\b([0-9]{4})[0-9]{0,9}([0-9]{4})\\b))", "$1--HIDDEN--,");
return result;
}
}
```

Input:

```
String text="+919913623683,,,,1,2,,,4328798712363938,,,,5673,,7,8";
```

output:

```
data="+919913623683,,,,1,2,,,************3988,,,,****,,7,8";
```

Comment: Word boundary between two digits will invalidate the match. You also have 4 groups, but are using only 1.

Comment: Could you please state clearly where in the string we should be looking for numbers and what they should look like? Do you want to obtain `+919913623683,,,,1,2,,,**************38,,,,****,,7,8`?

Comment: I don't want to save credit card numbers and pin directly into database. In this string I have both pin and credit card number so i need to mask them before saving.

Comment: Have a look at [what I suggest](http://ideone.com/6yS9zu). The regex is taking first 14 digits from a number or the whole 4-digit numbers and replaces them exactly with appropriate number of asterisks.

Comment: Thank u stribizhev.It works for me.

Comment: If Mena's solution works, too, I guess there is no point in posting my answer. Glad I could be of help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple & ugly example using chained `replaceAll` invocations would look like (note that the order here is important):

```
String text="+919913623683,,,,1,2,,,4328798712363938,,,,5673,,7,8";
System.out.println(
    text
    //           | not preceded by digit
    //           |      | 4 digits
    //           |      |      | not followed by digit
    //           |      |      |         | replace with literal ****
    .replaceAll("(?<=\\D)\\d{4}(?=\\D)", "****")
    //           | 12 digits
    //           |      | followed by 4 digits
    //           |      |            | replace with literal 12 *s
    .replaceAll("\\d{12}(?=\\d{4})", "************")
);
```

**Output**

```
+919913623683,,,,1,2,,,************3938,,,,****,,7,8
```

As mentioned, you need the first `replaceAll` invocation first. 
Otherwise you'd end up replacing the full 16-digit chunk with "*s", as it would match the condition for the 4-digit `replaceAll`.

Comment: Hello Mena, If i  want to mask everything after phone number whose length is greater than or equal to 4. For example , String data={+918398293978,,,,,,4324238989975667,,,,,3284,,,1,3,,,,,23894939392,,,,,} i want an output as follows  +918398293978,,,,,,************5667,,,,,****,,,1,3,,,,,*******9392